# Upgrade from Infinispan 8 to 12

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan

I am upgrading my project from a simple infinispan cache version 8 to 12, nothing fancy, just storing some serialized java objects on a file.
After upgrading to infinispan 12 it is no longer possible to serialize many native java types such as HashMap, resulting in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: Object of type class java.util.HashMap expected to be marshallable
```

How should I handle this? Is there a way to provide a marshaller for HashMap and such?

I tried without success changing the marshaller in the configuration xml file, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This resulted in an unnamed module error:

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller cannot be cast to class org.infinispan.commons.marshall.Marshaller (org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.PFC-1.0.ear' @53818c17; org.infinispan.commons.marshall.Marshaller is in unnamed module of loader 'org.infinispan.commons@12.1.4.Final' @4bf5c7a4)
```

Is there any other solution? How can I get this fixed as easily as possible?

Answer (score 0):

That implicit marshaller has been deprectaded. If you want to continue using it add it through this new explicit dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
   <artifactId>infinispan-jboss-marshalling</artifactId>
   <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
</dependency>
```